# How to customize the widget type of a field collection on Order Edit pages (/admin/commerce/orders/[order-number]/edit) in Drupal Commerce?

Tags: commerce, entities

I have a field collection inside the customer billing profile. Some orders have so many field collections (500+) that visiting /admin/commerce/orders/[order-number]/edit results in a white screen and this PHP / PDO error:
[image: PDO Error]

Viewing the order with 500+ field collections works fine, so my current approach is to simply to hide the field collection from being viewed when editing orders. Changing the field collection widget manually from "embedded" to "hidden" at /admin/commerce/customer-profiles/types/billing/fields/my_field_collection/widget-type hides the field collection and allows me to edit the order; however, this hides the field collection *everywhere*. I need it to only be "hidden" from the order edit page, but "embedded" everywhere else.

I've been stuck on this for a few days, so I would appreciate your assistance.